# Zend Translate ini adapter exception "Ini file 'Array' not found"

Tags: zend-framework, zend-translate

I get an ugly exception from Zend Translate:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Translate_Exception' with message 'Ini file 'Array' not found' in C:\www\libraries\ZendFramework-1.10.5-minimal\library\Zend\Translate\Adapter\Ini.php:54

**application.ini**

resources.translate.registry_key          = "Zend_Translate"
resources.translate.adapter               = "ini"
resources.translate.data.directory        = APPLICATION_PATH "/languages"
resources.translate.options.scan          = "directory"
resources.translate.locale            = "en"

**directory structure**

application\languages\
application\languages\en\component1.ini
application\languages\en\component2.ini
application\languages\el\component1.ini
application\languages\el\component2.ini

**the culprit - Zend\Translate\Adapter\Ini.php**

```
protected function _loadTranslationData($data, $locale, array $options = array()) {  
  $this->_data = array();  

  if (!file_exists($data)) {  
      require_once 'Zend/Translate/Exception.php';  
      throw new Zend_Translate_Exception("Ini file '".$data."' not found");  
  }
}
```

at this point var_dump($data) returns *

```
array(1) { 
   ["directory"] =>string(45) "C:\www\projects\helloworld\application/languages" 
}*
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should format that code because as it is its very hard to unerstand.

Comment: Just found out that double spaces -> br in markdown :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its just because your $data is "array", but should be a "string" that holds a filename.

In order to check the files for existence in the array of strings you should iterate through that array:

```
foreach ($data as $file) {
    if (!file_exists($file)) {  
         require_once 'Zend/Translate/Exception.php';  
         throw new Zend_Translate_Exception("Ini file '".$file."' not found");
    }
}
```